# Query execution and object mapping cost comparison

Tags: database, mongodb, entity-framework, hibernate, orm

Is the process of object mapping for relational databases more expensive than the process of Json parsing/mapping for document based databases? I believe both are relatively expensive operations because they involve string manipulation. I was usually concerned about the cost where databases execute queries. How much time mapping processes take relative to query execution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about database performance, benchmark your use case. You can perform thought experiments but there is so much variability in actual reality that thought experiments are not a substitute for benchmarking.

For MongoDB specifically, when a MongoDB query is constructed, sent to the server, executed, returned from the server and response passed back to application, none of these steps involve JSON in any way. Your question is meaningless for MongoDB.

Comment: No no my question is not about the database side. I'm asking about the process after databases returns results to application. I'm asking about the performance of the mapping of the results to objects of that application. And comparison of this process to database side in terms of speed.

Comment: JSON is not involved there either.

Comment: Doesn't mongo return string in Json format as query results? What you mean it's not involved?

Comment: Ok it's out of the context of this question because it's not about what it returns but the process of mapping it to an object. But if it doesn't return json string what it returns? i would like to know.

Comment: Client to server communication uses BSON which is a binary format.

Comment: Ok doesn't make much difference in terms of my question. How is it mapped to a C# object for example? How much time it would take in ms? For example simple queries to database takes around 30-40ms. I know it depends on lots of factors I'm just trying to get a rough comparison.